# Ruby - link_to - How to add data directly from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

First of all, I am very new to ruby and I am trying to maintain an application already running in production.

I have been so far able to "interpret" the code well, but there is one thing I am stuck at.

I have a haml.html file where I am trying to display links from DB.

Imagine a DB structure like below

```
link_name - Home
URL - /home.html
class - clear
id - homeId
```

I display a link on the page as below

```
< a href="/home.html" class="clear" id="home" > Home </a>
```

To do this I use 'link_to' where I am adding code as follows

```
-link_to model.link_name , model.url, {:class => model.class ...... }
```

Now I have a new requirement where we have a free text in DB, something like - 
`data-help="home-help" data-redirect="home-redirect"` which needs to come into the options.

So code in haml needs to directly display content versus assign it to a variable to display.

In other words I am able to do 
`attr= '"data-help="home-help" data-redirect="home-redirect"'` inside the `<a>`, but not able to do 
`data-help="home-help" data-redirect="home-redirect"`  in `<a>` tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`link_to` accepts a hash `:data => { :foo => "bar" }` of key/val pairs that it will build into data- attributes on the anchor tag. The above will create an attr as follows `data-foo="bar"`

So you could write a method on the model to grab `self.data_fields` (or whatever it's called) and split it into attr pairs and then create a hash from that.  Then you can just pass the hash directly to the :data param in link_to by  `:data => model.custom_data_fields_hash`

This somewhat verbose method splits things out and returns a hash that'd contain: `{"help"=>"home-help", "redirect"=>"home-redirect"}`

```
def custom_data_fields_hash

  # this would be replaced by  self.your_models_attr
  data_fields = 'data-help="home-help" data-redirect="home-redirect"'

  # split the full string by spaces into attr pairs
  field_pairs = data_fields.split " "

  results = {}

  field_pairs.each do |field_pair|

    # split the attr and value by the =
    data_attr, data_value = field_pair.split "="

    # remove the 'data-' substring because the link_to will add that in automatically for :data fields
    data_attr.gsub! "data-", ""

    # Strip the quotes, the helper will add those
    data_value.gsub! '"', ""

    # add the processed pair to the results
    results[data_attr] = data_value

  end

  results

end
```

Running this in a Rails console gives:

```
2.1.2 :065 > helper.link_to "Some Link", "http://foo.com/", :data => custom_data_fields_hash
 => "<a data-help=\"home-help\" data-redirect=\"home-redirect\" href=\"http://foo.com/\">Some Link</a>"
```

Alternatively you could make it a helper and just pass in the model.data_attr instead

```
link_to "Some Link", "http://foo.com/", :data => custom_data_fields_hash(model.data_fields_attr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could use the code you provided to render the data as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can directly embed an attribute string. You could try to decode the string in order to pass it to `link_to`:

```
- link_to model.link_name, model.url,
    {
      :class => model.class
    }.merge(Hash[
      str.scan(/([\w-]+)="([^"]*)"/)
    ])
  )
```